# Simplify an expression with inequalities assuming a symbol is an integer

Tags: sympy

I'm using SymPy to create a Kakuro solver but I'm having trouble enforcing that the symbols need to be integers. I've come so far that I get an inequality expression which look like this:

```
((1 <= x) & (x < 3/2)) | ((3/2 < x) & (x < 2))
```

The symbol `x` should equal to 1 so the expression is correct since 1 is the only possible integer.

How can I force `x` to be an integer?

I know there is diophantine solvers available in SymPy but these seem to only handle equations, not inequalities. I've tried creating the symbols using:

```
x = Symbol('x', integer=True)
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in way, but I wrote a function to simplify a relation of the kind you mentioned, assuming we work with integers.

There are eight rewrite rules: for example, `x <= number` is replaced by `x <= floor(number)`, and `x < number` is replaced by `x <= ceiling(number) - 1`, etc.

After these rules are applied, any remaining `And` parts of the expression are subjected to `reduce_inequalities`. Example:

```
expr = ((1 <= x) & (x < 3 / 2)) | ((3 / 2 < x) & (x < 2))
simplify_integer_relation(expr)   # returns Eq(x, 1)
```

Caveat: the rewrite rules assume we don't get do anything like `x/2` in the expression, creating an unknown fractional number. The assumption is that everything involving the unknown is an integer.

Code:

```
def simplify_integer_relation(expr):
    rewrite_rules = {
        GreaterThan: {
            "lhs": lambda z: floor(z),
            "rhs": lambda z: ceiling(z),
            "rel": GreaterThan,
        },
        LessThan: {
            "lhs": lambda z: ceiling(z),
            "rhs": lambda z: floor(z),
            "rel": LessThan,
        },
        StrictGreaterThan: {
            "lhs": lambda z: ceiling(z) - 1,
            "rhs": lambda z: floor(z) + 1,
            "rel": GreaterThan,
        },
        StrictLessThan: {
            "lhs": lambda z: floor(z) + 1,
            "rhs": lambda z: ceiling(z) - 1,
            "rel": LessThan,
        },
    }

    for rel in rewrite_rules:
        rule = rewrite_rules[rel]
        for atom in expr.atoms(rel):
            if atom.lhs.is_number:
                new_atom = rule["rel"](rule["lhs"](atom.lhs), atom.rhs)
                expr = expr.subs(atom, new_atom)
            elif atom.rhs.is_number:
                new_atom = rule["rel"](atom.lhs, rule["rhs"](atom.rhs))
                expr = expr.subs(atom, new_atom)

    for system in expr.atoms(And):
        expr = expr.subs(system, reduce_inequalities(system.args))

    return expr
```